# How to reset my computer turned-off display?

Tags: laptop

I closed the display on my laptop accidentally while personalizing my desktop (after right-clicking on my desktop) Without being able to see my desktop I am not able to turn the display back on. I used a VGA cable to connect to my TV screen but I can only get a display when I start up my laptop in Safe Mode. While in Safe mode I am not able to right-click on the desktop to personalize it because this function is not turned on in Safe Mode.

Can someone suggest a way that I can turn my laptop display back on. Thanks

PS: Dell Latitude 6400 laptop operating on Windows 7

Thanks a million, it worked!!
"laptop off, connecting the VGA cable, powering on the laptop and closing the lid right away" – By: Canadian Luke

Comment: What operating system (I assume Windows, but need to be sure)? What version? Have you tried turning the laptop off, connecting the VGA cable, powering on the laptop and closing the lid right away?

Comment: questions is missing basic information like, what OS, please don't assume people can just answer without knowing the full history, As these questions in such a way as if you are narrating a story that way people will be better suited to help you

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The site's Q&A format relies on questions being just questions and answers being solutions to them.  Including an answer within the question makes the question unclear, and others can't search for the answer.  Instead, please post the answer as an answer (read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer))

Answer (score 0):

Workaround

1. Login to Safe Mode
2. Create a new Admin Account
3. Login as that Admin account

let me know if the display settings are good with the new account